# Is the exponential syntax (1e2) in JavaScript number literals part of the IEEE 754 spec?

Tags: javascript, floating-point

Is the exponential syntax (e.g. `1e2`) in JavaScript number literals part of the IEEE 754 spec or a JavaScript-specific feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 754 spec is about how floating point is represented and how operations are carried out. It's not about textual representation of values in any particular language; in fact it really has nothing to do with programming languages in general other than as describing something that programming languages have to deal with.

The exponential notation JavaScript accepts is common with C, and therefore it *pre-dates* IEEE-754.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the "nEx" syntax dates back to FORTRAN in fact. I don't know who thought it up for programming languages but I suppose that'd make for an interesting blog post. Isn't that also basically how you write "scientific notation" in high school algebra?